# How to achieve that user is also the author of a task in Phabricator's Maniphest via Conduit API?

Tags: phabricator, maniphest

The Conduit API in Phabricator does not support setting of authorPHID parameter while calling maniphest.createtask. I can imagine this is because of security or some logical reason.

But I am developping my own frontend for Maniphest where the users (logged through Phabricator, so they are phab users and have phid) will add and edit tasks. What I need is that if a user creates task, he is also the author of the task.

But the problem is, that I can't connect to Conduit as any other user than "apibot" because I don't have others certificates in my front-end to do it. But if I log in as "apibot", then "apibot" is set as an author of the task.

Three possible solutions came to my mind:
1. retrieve certificate directly from phab's database
2. keep a list of certificates in some file in my front-end and update it manually everytime somebody will register
I guess none of them are really smart...
The third solution would be nice, but I didn't find a way, how to do it:
3. log in as "apibot", get certificate of userXY and then log in as the userXY

What would you suggest?

Comment: I have the same question. What I'm going to do is just add that person as a subscriber to the task using ccPHIDs. It's not ideal but at least they will get updates.